# C# - Looping won't stop (each iteration starts new Task)

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, task-parallel-library

So I have a basic solution to the Dining Philosopher's problem below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Conductor
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object _locker = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            object[] sticks = {new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object()};

            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                int next = (i + 1) % 5;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i], sticks[next], i)); 
            }
        }

        static void Eat(object _leftChopstick, object _rightChopstick, int i)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                lock (_leftChopstick)
                {
                    lock (_rightChopstick)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Eating" + i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst it may not be the most efficient solution, it throws an IndexOutOfRange exception on the "StartNew" call when i is set to 5.  I cannot figure out how using the Task Factory has somehow made my program ignore the for-loop condition.

If I run this code, it's fine:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Conductor
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object _locker = new object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            object[] sticks = { new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object(),
                               new object()};

            int i = 0;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i], sticks[i + 1], i));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i+1], sticks[i + 2], i + 1));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i+2], sticks[i + 3], i + 2));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i+3], sticks[i + 4], i + 3));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[i + 4], sticks[0], i + 4));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Eat(object _leftChopstick, object _rightChopstick, int i)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                lock (_leftChopstick)
                {
                    lock (_rightChopstick)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Eating" + i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if I debug through the loop, I get the same exception.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry if it's too basic or if there's some trivial flaw in my code I've missed.  Thanks.

Comment: use the debugger and step through the code.. don't just `CODE AND GO` meaning write code and launch the application expecting to have `Zero` errors..

Comment: Yep I did that too.  I've edited my answer to say that.  Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                int next = (i + 1) % 5;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Eat(sticks[j], sticks[next], j));
            }
```

Comment: The problem was in the scope change of the reference to `i` when Task.Factory was involved. By assigning a local variable to only be consumed by a single target process, you avoid the risk of the higher scope variable being modified by outside factors.